# Where should I set my DB password used by Play Framework?

Tags: git, version-control, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm new to Play framework. I'm trying to set it up to connect to a PostgreSQL database and I was wondering where I should configure the DB password which is to be used.

The documentation seems to suggest setting it up in `application.conf` using the `db.default.password` property, but I thought that it was never a good idea to keep such delicate information in files under version control, especially for projects hosted on GitHub or any open source hosting platform.

Any suggestions on where I could set it up without it being submitted to version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionConfiguration

Typically you either have a separate config file or you store secret values in environment variables.

Comment: Thanks! I chose using an environment variable.